# NameError: global name 'operator' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

```
import KNN
def c(i,d,l,k):
    dss=d.shape[0]
    dm=tile(i,(dss,1))-d
    sqm=dm**2
    sqd=sqm.sum(axis=1)
    dist=sqd**0.5
    sDI=dist.argsort()
    clc={}
    for i in range(k):
        vl=l[sDI[i]]
        clc[vl]=clc.get(vl,0)+1     
    sCC=sorted(clc.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
    return sCC[0][0]

c([0,0],g,l,3)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    c([0,0],g,l,3)
  File "<pyshell#31>", line 12, in c
    sCC=sorted(clc.items(),key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
NameError: global name 'operator' is not defined
```

KNN contains the following code:

```
from numpy import *
import operator

def createDataSet():
    group = array([[1.0,1.1],[1.0,1.0],[0,0],[0,0.1]])
    labels = ['A','A','B','B']
    return group, labels
```

Why is there a error as mentioned above? Program is run on Python 3.3.2. This code is a simple k-classification algorithm run in Python.

Comment: Where you `import KNN` you ought to also `import operator`.

Answer (score 21):

You need to `import operator` into the local namespace; `import KNN` will not also import the submodules it imports.

As a rule, you need to be explicit about any and all modules and objects you use, with the exception of the `builtins` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html).

Unlike some other languages, there are no implicit imports.

Advanced tip/editorial on imports: 
You might be tempted to use `KNN.operator`. It's available there because it was imported by `KNN`. However, this is almost always a regrettable decision, as confuses the picture: Is this a special module? If so what's its interface? Save the cuteness, be explicit.

Comment: `import KNN` does import `operator` and make it available as `KNN.operator`, it just doesn't make it available as `operator`. Which means you could write `KNN.operator.itemgetter` if you really wanted to. But that would be silly. If you want to use `operator`, it doesn't matter than some other module also wants to use it; just import it.

Comment: @abarnert - true it does "expose" - but not in the way Pavan expected.

Comment: Yeah, I think you explained it well enough to answer the OP's question, and most people who will come searching with similar questions; I just thought the comment might be useful for people who know a _little_ bit more, but not quite enough more.