# Python, object to list and sorted

Tags: python

ive added all my objects to a list but they are not sorted, i want to sort the entries in the list via LevelNo, so 1 then two.

the error im getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pagerduty.py", line 143, in <module>
    OnCallData = OnCallData.sort(key=operator.itemgetter('LevelNo'))
NameError: name 'operator' is not defined
```

my current code is

```
from operator import itemgetter
class User(object):
    __attrs = ['Policy','Level', 'LevelNo', 'StartDate', 'EndDate', 'StartTime',
               'EndTime', 'Name', 'Mobile']

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for attr in self.__attrs:
            setattr(self, attr, kwargs.get(attr, None))

    def __repr__(self):
        return ', '.join(
            ['%s: %r' % (attr, getattr(self, attr)) for attr in self.__attrs])  


OnCallData = [] 
for UserItem in objPolicyData['users']:   
    UserData = User()     
    UserData.Name = UserItem['name']
    UserData.Mobile = UserMobile = getUserMobile(UserItem['id']) 
    for OnCall in UserItem['on_call']:    
        UserPolicy = OnCall['escalation_policy'] 
        PolicyName = UserPolicy['name']
        if PolicyName.lower().find('test') == -1:      
            UserData.Policy = PolicyName
            UserData.LevelNo = OnCall['level']
            UserData.Level = getLevel(OnCall['level'])
            UserData.StartDate = getDate(OnCall['start'])
            UserData.EndDate = getDate(OnCall['end'])
            UserData.StartTime = getTime(OnCall['start'])
            UserData.EndTime = getTime(OnCall['end'])    
            OnCallData.append(UserData)

OnCallData = sorted(OnCallData, key=itemgetter('LevelNo'))
```

sample data is

```
[
Policy: u'Network Team', Level: 'Backup On Call Engineer', LevelNo: 2, StartDate: 'Monday 02 May', EndDate: 'Monday 09 May', StartTime: '09:00AM', EndTime: '09:00AM', Name: u'John Smith', Mobile: u'07XXX', 
Policy: u'System Administator Team', Level: 'Primary On Call Engineer', LevelNo: 1, StartDate: 'Tuesday 03 May', EndDate: 'Tuesday 03 May', StartTime: '09:00AM', EndTime: '05:00PM', Name: u'Billy Bones', Mobile: u'07XXX', 
Policy: u'Network Team', Level: 'Primary On Call Engineer', LevelNo: 1, StartDate: 'Friday 29 April', EndDate: 'Tuesday 03 May', StartTime: '05:00PM', EndTime: '03:30PM', Name: u'Jim Bob', Mobile: '07XXX'
]
```

Comment: Duplicate question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553091/python-error-on-operator-keyword

Comment: Have you even imported `operator` module?

Comment: hi yes ive imported item getter, added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work too

```
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: x['b'])
[{'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 3}, {'a': 1, 'c': 2, 'b': 4}]
>>>
```

PS: I used dummy data because your data wasn't proper python struct.

In your case it would be

```
_OnCallData = sorted(OnCallData, key=lambda x: x.LevelNo)
```

Comment: how do i get my data in proper struct?

Comment: @AlexW I mean a list of dictionaries(curly braces missing in your data) with string keys(quotes missing in your keys)

Comment: i am using a class to create my list item, and dynamically adding each class to the list, do i need to do something additional to get correct struct?

Comment: No. Your repr function confused me. I'm sorry. Have updated my answer for your ques without operator.

Comment: i think this has got it

Answer (score 1):

You need to import `itemgetter`. Add `from operator import itemgetter` to the top of your code first.

Comment: That's not all.  That won't define `operator`; it will define `itemgetter`.  Therefore, `key=operator.itemgetter` would need to change to `key=itemgetter`

Comment: The original code was using `itemgetter` directly :) Anyway, I think he also should use `attrgetter` if he's using objects like he seems to be.

Comment: Interesting.  The error indicates that he used `operator.itemgetter`, but the code indicates that he used `itemgetter`.

Comment: @tayfun as im using an object i should use attrgetter instead? do i import that the same way as itemgetter?

Answer (score -1):

This Should work.

```
def update(): #This defines the update procedure
    input_file=open("Scores.txt","r")      

    name=input("Enter name") #Uses variable to store name that is asked for
    highScore=input("Enter current high score")     
    newHighscore=input("Enter new high score")    

    data=input_file.read().splitlines()                    

    input_file.close    

    position=0 #Placing of the data at the start

    found=False
```